# [C#]Response.write is not working when use Thread

Tags: c#, asp.net

In main method I use this thread to call the send email function.

```
    protected void updateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                
    Thread email = new Thread(delegate ()
            {
                sendmail(//send some string);
            });
            email.IsBackground = true;
            email.Start();
    }
```

There some Response.Write in sendmail() method and when I'm trying to debug it's show error

> System.Web.HttpException: 'Response is not available in this context.'

This is sendmail()

```
private void sendmail(//string input)
{
       //do something about smtp
       Response.Write("Test message");
}
```

Comment: Where you have written the Response.Write? right now I can't see in your code

Comment: There is no reason to use the `Thread` class these days unless you have a specific use case. sendmail should be async as its doing IO. this should all just use the async and await pattern

Comment: @PurveshPatel Sorry, Now I edited to add Response.Write.

Answer (score 1):

The `Response` object is associated with the button event handler and not available in the new thread you start.

The event handler exits shortly after you start the new thread. Anything written to `Response` must be done before that handler returns.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code it's working perfectly

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //GetData();

                CheckThread();
            }
        }

        private void CheckThread()
        {
            Thread email = new Thread(delegate ()
            {
                sendmail();
            });
            email.IsBackground = true;
            email.Start();
        }

        private void sendmail()
        {
            Response.Write("Call this function!");
        }
```

[image]